# node server not returning response for this particular data set

Tags: javascript, node.js

I aa running a node server returning data for fetchdata api.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

const z = { 'a': 'tobi' };
app.get('/fetchdata', function (req, res) {
  res.json(z);
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

In second scenario i am running a node server consuming the api provided by first node.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3001


app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(`
<html>
    <body>Hello user!!</body>
    <script>
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/fetchdata', {mode: 'no-cors'})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res))
    </script>
</html>
`));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

I am not able to get any response in the second case. Api displays blank response. If i am keeping `z = [{ 'a': 'tobi' }]`; it works fine. It only fails for previous value of z.

Comment: Can you open `http://localhost:3000/fetchdata` in the browser?

Comment: Yes. It works file in browser tab